# MYSQL connector saying it has connected even with the wrong username?

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, port-scanning

I am building a database connection scanner for my security course at university. I have used DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, password) and it seems to work fine but with one exception that I just cannot understand. If I enter the wrong username it is still returning a connection??? my test code is pasted below. Any pointers would be much appreciated. It returns the correct error if I put the wrong password in, if I turn the server off it tells me. But for some unknown reason it will not tell me if the username is wrong, its as if its not even checking!

```
public class DBConnector {


Connection connection = null;
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
String userName;
String password;


public DBConnector() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Connection tryConnection(String username, String password){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);

        System.out.println("Connected");

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        System.out.println("No Connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Refused");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Sql Ex");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection; 

}
}
```

And here is my main class to run the method.

```
public class MainTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DBConnector dbc = new DBConnector();

    dbc.tryConnection("", "");

}

}
```

Maybe this has something to do with running the test on "Localhost"?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you connect to the database instance without a username or password with the mysql client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you are logging in as an [anonymous user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html).

You can make your local MySQL Server installation more secure (and hence force your code above to throw an error) by removing the anonymous user like this:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then try connecting with no username and password.

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured out the problem and it was pretty much what you described, I had given no password to the user "root" which apparently overrides the security features and allows for anonymous users. Solved it now thank you very much